# regex / ng-pattern to accept certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm using Angular's form validation with `ng-pattern` to validate a username with Special Charter

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+@+[a-z]*$/"
```

**My problem** is that is limited to only one type of *Special Charter* to be placed at required place.

I would like this to support any of the special characters we use in alphabets

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Like ng-pattern only for 31 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear of what you define a Special Character, therefore assuming by your example that `@` is a Special Character.

**For example**, if you want to support the characters `@`, `!` and `#`, you will modify the regular expression like this:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+[@+!+#][a-z]*$/"
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/cIjpI9LAJKgs1MvZmBJv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9/&quot&quot\\\]\[:;|=,+*?<>]+$/
```

allows: characters, digits and
" / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? <>